# show text under image in place of overlay

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to move the text from over the image to displaying under the image on mobile. 
The image is being displayed using

```
    <article class="post-featured post-6792 post type-post status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry category-tech format-standard mobile-video post-visible" style="background-image: url(http://theoldcontinent.mgtestsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Schermafbeelding-2017-07-10-om-18.54.13-530x300.jpg);" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnfNta6SosA">
<div class="overlay-container">

<div class="overlay-content">
  <h2 class="entry-title">Kermit the Frog (Jordan Peterson) telling you to clean your room</h2>
</div>
```

currently the .overlay-content is showing ontop of the video on mobile. If I move it down using

```
 .overlay-content {
        top: 300px;
        background-color: #fff; 
        color: #000;
    }
```

then it is hidden and doesn't show. 
You can see the issue here http://theoldcontinent.mgtestsite.com/ only on mobile if you scroll down to the 4th text - Kermit the frog 
How do I create space under the image to show the text (Wordpress site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin-top: 195px;` worked and fixed the issue